# How can I disable bluetooth earphones from automatic playing audio as soon as they are connected?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiosession

I'm building an audio application for iOS in Swift.

Every time I connect my bluetooth earphones, it automatically starts playing music from my Music (iTunes) app. I'm on iOS 14.4.

Is it possible to disable this behavior programatically? Or this behavior is preempted from my specific bluetooth earphones?

Is it related to [AVAudioSession.RouteSharingPolicy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/routesharingpolicy)?

Comment: I dont think it has anything to do with RouteSharingPolicy. That kind of sounds like an issue with the headphones themselves. Have you tired any other headphones?